# ¿Cómo extraer de una lista el diccionario con mayor valor?

Tags: python

Buenas tengo que hacer el siguiente ejercicio en Python:

Escriba una función llamada `libro_precio_alto_libro` que tome la lista de "libros" de diccionarios definida anteriormente y devuelva el diccionario que contiene el título, el precio y el autor del libro con el libro con el precio más alto.

Esto es lo que nos dan:

```
books = [
    {
        "title": "Genetic Algorithms and Machine Learning for Programmers",
        "price": 36.99,
        "author": "Frances Buontempo"
    },
    {
        "title": "The Visual Display of Quantitative Information",
        "price": 38.00,
        "author": "Edward Tufte"
    },
    {
        "title": "Practical Object-Oriented Design",
        "author": "Sandi Metz",
        "price": 30.47
    },
    {
        "title": "Weapons of Math Destruction",
        "author": "Cathy O'Neil",
        "price": 17.44
    }
]
```

Espero me puedan ayudar y muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Samuel, tendrías que indicar en la pregunta qué has intentado (incluyendo el código correspondiente adecuadamente formateado) y con qué resultados. De esa manera es más probable que obtengas buenas respuestas. Un saludo.

Comment: `mayor_precio=sorted(books, key=lambda x: x["price"])[-1]`

Comment: Samuel por favor agrega lo que has intentado para poder ayudarte

Comment: @CandidMoe no tendríamos que pedirle lo que ha hecho antes de ayudarlo?, ya que sería hacer el codigo por el

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía. Todavía tiene que escribir la función ...

Comment: @CandidMoe o ya veo, buen punto

Comment: @CandidMoe también se puede usar la función max: `max(books, key=lambda x:x['price'])`.